# Strange error after file downloading swift

Tags: ios, swift, download-manager

I'm trying to download file from remote server. File is available and downloading also completes. File name I send to this function from collectionview with files, so name is correct. But I have some problems with file saving. Here is my way of file loading:

```
func testLoad(attachName:String) {
        let documentsUrl:URL =  (FileManager.default.urls(for: .downloadsDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first as URL?)!
        let destinationFileUrl = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent(attachName)
        
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: Pathes.init(endpoint: "message/\(mModel?.id ?? -1)/attachment/\(attachName)?type=\(mType ?? -1)").resourseUrl)
        
        request.setValue("application/json; charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("Bearer " + UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "access_token")!, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        
        let task = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default).downloadTask(with: request) { (tempLocalUrl, response, error) in
            if let tempLocalUrl = tempLocalUrl, error == nil {
                
                print("\(tempLocalUrl) ---> \(destinationFileUrl)")
                
                if ((response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode) != nil {
                    do {
                        try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: tempLocalUrl, to: destinationFileUrl)
                    } catch (let writeError) {
                        print("Error creating a file \(destinationFileUrl) : \(writeError)")
                    }
                }
                
            } else {
                print("Error took place while downloading a file. Error description: %@", error?.localizedDescription);
            }
        }
        task.resume()
        
    }
```

And below you can see my error:

```
Error creating a file file:///Users/angor/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B83E640A-8EC4-475A-B272-5D884B611A8B/data/Containers/Data/Application/3DE475CE-B2B3-4971-9382-1F272160B1A4/Downloads/paolo-nicolello-dqy5wtCdS4U-unsplash.jpg : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=516 "“CFNetworkDownload_mw7QwY.tmp” couldn’t be copied to “Downloads” because an item with the same name already exists." UserInfo={NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/Users/angor/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B83E640A-8EC4-475A-B272-5D884B611A8B/data/Containers/Data/Application/3DE475CE-B2B3-4971-9382-1F272160B1A4/tmp/CFNetworkDownload_mw7QwY.tmp, NSUserStringVariant=(
    Copy
), NSDestinationFilePath=/Users/angor/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B83E640A-8EC4-475A-B272-5D884B611A8B/data/Containers/Data/Application/3DE475CE-B2B3-4971-9382-1F272160B1A4/Downloads/paolo-nicolello-dqy5wtCdS4U-unsplash.jpg, NSFilePath=/Users/angor/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B83E640A-8EC4-475A-B272-5D884B611A8B/data/Containers/Data/Application/3DE475CE-B2B3-4971-9382-1F272160B1A4/tmp/CFNetworkDownload_mw7QwY.tmp, NSUnderlyingError=0x60000232c150 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=17 "File exists"}}
```

I can't understand why it happens. The error says that my file exists but I don't see any new files in my `Downloads` directory. I think that that the problem is connected with temporary file which has to be copied to `Downloads`. I found this way of file downloading [here](http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/code-examples/download-file-from-a-remote-url-in-swift/) maybe I did smth wrong?

Comment: "but I don't see any new files in my Downloads directory" And what if you use `FileManager` to check if a file exists at path?

Comment: @Larme, how I can do it? I don't see any new files in directory :)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1415645-fileexists ?

Comment: No this file doesn't exists, I checked it :( I think that due to the error I can't copy it :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to figure out where the problem is :) I added removing temporary created file from `tmp` folder and also moved all file downloading code to extension:

```
extension UIViewController:URLSessionDownloadDelegate{
    public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
        guard let url = downloadTask.originalRequest?.url else { return }
        let documentsPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .downloadsDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        let destinationURL = documentsPath.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
       
        try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: destinationURL)
        
        do {
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: location, to: destinationURL)
            
        } catch let error {
            print("Copy Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe it will help someone else except me :)

Comment: Without .removeItem i cant have acess to file, thx for your solution.